# Checking if a JTextField is Empty or less than 1

Tags: java

When testing my program this if statement doesn't the issue.
If I enter a number less than 1 the if statement works and catches it however when I leave the field blank the if statement does not catch it.

```java
String txt = txtQuantity.getText();
if (Integer.parseInt(txt) < 1 || txt.equals("")) {
    lblErrorMessage.setText("Error: Please enter a quantity =>1.");
}
```

Comment: The obvious thing is to reverse the order of your two tests. I would also call `trim()`

Comment: try this    if( txt.isEmpty()  || Integer.parseInt(txt) < 1)

Comment: This works, but why?

Comment: Unless you have a filter attached to you textfield which only allows for integer numbers to be entered, it would be a good idea to ensure what is entered into that field is indeed the number type desired: `if (txt.isEmpty() || !txt.matches("\\d+") || Integer.parseInt(txt) < 1) {`.

Comment: I really think you'll get further if you explain it to yourself. Have a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Comment: Because the first `if` condition (`txt.isEmpty()`) is testing to see if there is something to parse into Integer first (you can't parse an empty string). If it fails then there is no sense to carry on with the other `if` conditions and it jumps right into the `if` code block code and issues the error message.

Comment: In your error message use `>=`. The reverse sequence is often used as arrow, and some people might have problems understanding what you are after.

Comment: [`String#isBlank`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank())